# merging two tables but removing duplicates in in a certain column

Tags: sql

so I am trying to merge two tables for example

table 1:

| name | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| David | W | C |
| BOB | v | w |

---

table 2:

| name | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| David | o | n |
| Kevin | l | x |

Im trying to merge them such as if I have a duplicate name in table 1 and table 2, ill keep only the one in table 1
so table 3 would be like this

table 3:

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| David | W | C |
| Bob | v | w |
| Kevin | l | x |

if I use union or union all, it creates 2 rows of David but I need only one of them

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.name, t2.name), t1.center, t2.right
from table_1 t1 full join
     table_2 t2
     on t1.name = t2.name;
```

Comment: never thought to use COALESCE here. I learned something as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what your goal is, if a match is found in col1/col2 in both tables. but try this:

```
SELECT
           table1.name
          ,table1.col1
          ,table1.col2
          ,table2.col1
          ,table2.col2

FROM table_1 AS table1
FULL JOIN table_2 AS table2
ON table1.name = table2.name
```

This will join `table_1` and `table_2` on the name column
It will return null values in `table1.col1`/`col2` and `table2.col1`/`col2` if a match is not found

Comment: This does not return "Kevin" in the result set.